# Atom shows type info tooltips at random cursor positions

Tags: typescript, atom-editor

My atom shows me type info from atom-typescript. But the type info i get seem to be not related with the cursor position. I even get type info when my cursor points at empty lines. It seems like atom-typescript or atom itself has problems with my scroll position. If i scroll one line, my "type info on hover" feature is offset by one line.

[image]

What can i do about this? What plugin is responsible for this?

Edit: I have no plugin installed except atom-typescript and its dependencies. Also no themes. No customization at all.

Comment: did you find any solution yet ?

Comment: @vamshi-krishna  I have not found a solution, but the issue is gone. I guess it has disappeared with any atom/package updates.

Answer (score 0):

You could try modifying the css for your tooltips in your theme. Try:

1. Command-Shift-P to open your Package menu and type 'Change Themes',
   then click the selection.
2. At the top of the page, click the link that says 'You can also style Atom by editing your stylesheet'.
3. Without knowing the theme you're using and any styling within, I'm going to guess that you should add something like the following:

   **.tooltip {
   position: relative; top: -30px;
   }**

That might give you the offset you're looking for.